# where the log of gcloud logging winston written to

Tags: logging, gcloud, winston, google-cloud-stackdriver

i'm using @google-cloud/logging-winston

and flow this quickstart

```
const winston = require('winston');

const {LoggingWinston} = require('@google-cloud/logging-winston');

const loggingWinston = new LoggingWinston();


const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'info',
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console(),
    loggingWinston,
  ],
});


logger.error('warp nacelles offline');
logger.info('shields at 99%');
```

in below, there're the comment that:

> Logs will be written to: "projects/YOUR_PROJECT_ID/logs/winston_log"

but i can't find it any where, even LOGGING in gcloud console

[image]

Where can i find these log

many thanks

Comment: I have followed the same [steps](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/nodejs#using_winston) you mentioned and run the code on a Google App Engine standard application. I get those logs just fine. Where is you code running, is it deployed in a GAE application, a Compute Engine instance..? On the other hand, I see you are looking for the logs in a Service Account, you should check the component you are using.

Comment: The log data will be written to the resource `Global` and to the log `winston_log` Change the control where you have `Service Account, logger@...` to `Global`.

Comment: @PabloAlmécijaRodríguez I'm run the code on my local  machine using ServiceAccount
JohnHanley I found it in Global!. So many thanks to you.
the point is i thought that the log will be in Service account I provided so didnt find it

Comment: @JohnHanley Could you put your comment as an answer so that it has more visibility for other users who may experience this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The log data will be written to the Stackdriver Logging resource Global and to the log `winston_log`.

Go to the Google Cloud Console. Select Stackdriver Logging.

Under the `Filter by label or text search` is a drop down list.

Select `Global`. Next to this control is `All logs`. Select `winson_log`.